# Vulkan Vertex Buffer C

Tags: c, buffer, shader, vulkan

I am attempting to create a vertex buffer in Vulkan using C. When attempting to pass vertex data to the GPU nothing is displayed. Additionally having validation layers on, no errors or warnings are raised. I have tried changing the buffer size or using a different data set and checking the size of the buffers but to no avail.

Posted below is the relevant sections of code for creating the buffer.

Vertex data struct:

```
typedef struct vertexData {
    vec2 pos;
    vec3 color;
} vertexData;
```

Vertex data:

```
const vertexData vertices[3] = {
    {{0.0f,-0.5},{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}},
    {{0.5f,0.5},{0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}},
    {{-0.5f,0.5},{0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}},
};
```

Vertex descriptions:

```
static VkVertexInputBindingDescription getBindingDescription() {
    VkVertexInputBindingDescription bindingDescription ={
        .binding = 0,
        .stride = sizeof(vertexData),
        .inputRate = VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX,
    };
    return bindingDescription;
}

static VkVertexInputAttributeDescription *getAttributeDescriptions() {
    VkVertexInputAttributeDescription *attributeDescriptions = malloc(2*sizeof(VkVertexInputAttributeDescription));
    attributeDescriptions[0].binding = 0;
    attributeDescriptions[0].location = 0;
    attributeDescriptions[0].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32_SFLOAT;
    attributeDescriptions[0].offset = offsetof(vertexData, pos);

    attributeDescriptions[1].binding = 0;
    attributeDescriptions[1].location = 1;
    attributeDescriptions[1].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT;
    attributeDescriptions[1].offset = offsetof(vertexData, color);

    return attributeDescriptions;
}
```

Creating the vertex info:

```
VkVertexInputBindingDescription bindingDescription = getBindingDescription();
VkVertexInputAttributeDescription *attributeDescriptions;
attributeDescriptions = getAttributeDescriptions();
VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertexInputInfo = {
    .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO,
    .vertexBindingDescriptionCount = 1,
    .pVertexBindingDescriptions = &bindingDescription,
    .vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = 2,
    .pVertexAttributeDescriptions = attributeDescriptions,
};
```

Creating the actual vertex buffer:

```
void createVertexBuffer() {
    VkBufferCreateInfo bufferInfo = {
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO,
        .size = sizeof(vertices),
        .usage = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT,
        .sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE,
    };

    if(vkCreateBuffer(device, &bufferInfo, NULL, &vertexBuffer) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Failed to create vertex buffer.\n");
        cleanup();
    }

    VkMemoryRequirements memRequirements;
    vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements(device, vertexBuffer, &memRequirements);

    VkMemoryAllocateInfo allocInfo = {
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO,
        .allocationSize = memRequirements.size,
        .memoryTypeIndex = findMemoryType(memRequirements.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT),
    };

    if(vkAllocateMemory(device, &allocInfo, NULL, &vertexBufferMemory) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Failed to allocate vertex buffer memory.\n");
        cleanup();
    }
    vkBindBufferMemory(device, vertexBuffer, vertexBufferMemory, 0);

    void *data;
    vkMapMemory(device, vertexBufferMemory, 0, bufferInfo.size, 0, &data);
        memcpy(data, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    vkUnmapMemory(device, vertexBufferMemory);
}
```

And finally the actual draw command:

```
vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,  graphicsPipeline);
    VkBuffer vertexBuffers[] = {vertexBuffer};
    VkDeviceSize offsets[] = {0};
    vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, vertexBuffers, offsets);
    vkCmdDraw(commandBuffers[i], (uint32_t)sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(vertices[0]), 1, 0, 0);
```

The shaders are simple pass through shaders. They work when vertex data is hardcoded into them. The most I have been able to display is what looks like junk data on screen, which I believe was just allocating random/incorrect memory to the buffer. With the code in the current state nothing is displayed.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What you have shown LGTM. You should test error codes of `vkBindBufferMemory` and `vkMapMemory`. Validation can be finicky -- test it is actually working by breaking something. Make sure you did not forget `vkQueueSubmit` or `vkQueuePresentKHR`.

Comment: PS: It can be any number of things. While not particulary SO style, full code and\or `api_dump` might help here.

Comment: PS2: `(uint32_t)sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(vertices[0])`. Assuming it compiles it should be okay, but type-cast have precedence over division.

Comment: Checked the return values from vkBindBufferMemory and vkMapMemory and they did return VK_SUCCESS.  Both vkQueueSubmit or vkQueuePresentKHR are called in the render loop. Looking at the code some more I think the error could be in how I am mapping the memory with vkMapMemory, but not entirely sure how to test that. Full code is here https://github.com/TJGreen0211/vulkan/tree/master/src

Comment: Thank you for your pointers in narrowing down the issue. The issue had to do with the memcpy for the vertexData struct.